# Lombok builder override default constructor

Tags: java, builder, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I was setting the value of recordId from the child classes using the default constructor and was not using lombok `@Builder` initially. Eventually i decided to use the Builder here, but the problem now is lombok Builder overrides my default constructor internally hence the value is never set.

How can I put any hook too make lombok `@Builder` use my default constructor?

**Parent class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Record {
    private String recordId;
}
```

**Child class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public  class SRecord extends Record {
    private static final String RECORD_ID = "REC001";
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public SRecord() {
        setRecordId(RECORD_ID); //value of recordId being set
    }
}
```

Comment: haha yup i did upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Lombok's `@Builder` simply does not use the default constructor. It passes its values to an all-args constructor so that this constructor can fill the new instance with these values. `@Builder` does not use setters or direct access to the fields to do so. So your default constructor is simply ignored by `@Builder`.

What you can do is write your own all-args constructor. In it, you set your value for `recordId` and assign the rest of the fields from the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create a constructor in your base class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Record {

    private String recordId;

    public Record(String recordId) {
        this.recordId = recordId;
    }
}
```

Then use it in the constructor of the inherited class:

```
@Getter
@Setter   
@Builder
public class SRecord extends Record {

    private static final String RECORD_ID = "REC001";

    private String street;
    private String city;  

    public SRecord(String street, String city) {
        super(RECORD_ID); 
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

P.S. If you want to use Lombok Builder with **inheritance** you can use this [technique](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance).

Comment: Lombok 1.18.2 added `@SuperBuilder`, which is in most inheritance cases superior to the workaround you linked to.

Comment: @JanRieke That's right but it's [not supported yet in IDEA](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/513)...

Comment: Yep, it's a pity :(